# .live("click") event not working on ios safari and even onclick='' isnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I am trying to implement a drop-down menu in my navbar. Everything seems to work just fine on my desktop, but on the phone, my jquery .live("click") doesnt seem to be working. I tried adding onclick='' also, but it doesn't seem to work!

This is the code I've been implemting

## HTML

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a id="notif-load-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick='' href="/notifications/"><b data-icon="&#xe01d;"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu2 pull-left">
      <h3 class="lead" style="margin-left:25px;">Activity Feed</h3>
      <hr>
      <span id="notif-load"></span>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

## JS

```
$('#notif-load-dropdown').live('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var checkclass = $('#notif-load-dropdown').parent().hasClass('open');
  var b = $('html');
  if (checkclass){
    var w = $(document).width();
    var h = $(document).height();
    $('#notif-load').css({
      position: 'relative',
      top     : 0,
      left    : 0,
      zIndex  : 100
    });
    var $overlay = $('<div/>', {
    'id': 'overlay',
      css: {
        position   : 'absolute',
        height     : h + 'px',
        width      : w + 'px',
        left       : 0,
        top        : 0,
        background : '#000',
        opacity    : 0.5,
        zIndex     : 99
      }
    }).appendTo('body');
    b = $('html');
    b.css('overflow', 'hidden');
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#notif-load').load(href);
    var chkaclass = $('#notif-load a').hasClass('endless_more');
    if (!checkclass){
      $('#notif-load a').live('click', function(event){
        $('#notif-load').load('/notifications/allread/').load(href);
      });
    }
    $('#overlay').click(function(){
      $(this).remove();
      $('#notif-load').load('/notifications/allread/');
      $('#unread-notif').load('/isunread/');
      $('#notif-load').empty();
      b.css('overflow', 'auto');
    });
  }
  else
  {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    $('#notif-load').load('/notifications/allread/');
    $('#unread-notif').load('/isunread/');
    $('#notif-load').empty();
    //$('#notif-load-dropdown').parent().removeClass('open');
    b.css('overflow', 'auto');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. If you are using version 1.9 and above, `live` is removed.

Comment: Try with http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @nhahtdh I wansnt aware about that. I am using jquery 1.8 though. But if live is removed, how would you add these properties to dynamic elements?

Comment: @elclanrs I tried on, as described in one of the answers. it doesnt seem to work though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not exactly clear what is not working.

If the problem is that CLICK handler is not called at all then you can try to use touch events like `"touchstart"` or `"touchend"` because on touch devices you don't have mouse pointer so you can't "click". I am using [jquery.tappable.js](https://github.com/aanand/jquery.tappable.js) and it works fine for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I tried touchend, and it works just fine with that. thank you

Comment: just a note - touch events may not work on desktop browsers so you should consider using some lib or plugin which will use correct event handler if you want to target both mobile and desktop.

Comment: I am using both 'click touchend' , so that takes care of my desktop as well

Comment: Just make sure you handler is not called twice if browser supports both events.

Answer (score 4):

iOS doesn't accept click. You can use event "touchend".

instead:

```
$('#notif-load-dropdown').live('click', function(event){...});
and $('#notif-load a').live('click', function(event){...});
```

write

```
$('#notif-load-dropdown').bind('click touchend' ,function(event){...});
```

AND:
for jQuery 1.7 and up:

```
$('#notif-load').on('click touchend', 'a', function(event){...});
```

before jQuery 1.7:

```
$('#notif-load').delegate('a', 'click touchend', function(event){...});
```

[jsbin sample](http://jsbin.com/iwiziv/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', '#notif-load-dropdown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#notif-load').load(this.href);
});
```

replace document with closest non-dynamic parent.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work! It's still not showing my dropdown content in my ipad simulator, but its working fine on the desktop browsers

Comment: It's really impossible to answer that, as the posted code should work just fine on an iPad, I use it all the time, and I have an actual iPad to test with, and it always works for me. Either there is some other code messing it up or your simulator is'nt working ??

Comment: I am not sure what exactly the problem is, but I've tried almost all the solutions that I could find online. Anyways I've updated my JS logic. Please have a look, This is the complete logic that I am using for my dropdown

Answer (score 1):

live() is deprecated, load() is also deprecated since jQuery 1.8.

Anyway, try this:

```
$('#notif-load-dropdown').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#notif-load').load(href, {}, function(response) {
        $(this).html(response);
        //alert(response); // show server response, if there is no response, then the issue could be from the server side
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: even This doesnt seem to work! It's still not showing my dropdown content in my ipad simulator, but its working fine on the desktop browsers

Answer (score 1):

The 'click' event seems to be triggered only on 'a' tags, and maybe others, but definitively not on 'body' and 'div'.